# need help understanding how to use dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, hash, swift3

I am a novice with regards to the swift 3 programming language though I am familiar basically with C++.

I am trying to learn to use dictionaries in Swift 3; which I believe are similar to hashes in C++. I have a dictionary with several key:value pairs in it.
I want to take a certain, single key (which I won't know in advance) and extract from that dictionary the corresponding value.
I know there will be a single key with that name, although the same value will be associated with keys of different names.
After extracting that value from the key:value pair of that dictionary then I want to store that single value in a variable as a string.

What type of code could do that?

I found some code that seems it might be helpful but I'm not sure and I'm not sure too how to use that code(how to write it actually) to make it perform as I wish.

```
    extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {

   func someKeyFor(value: Value) -> Key? {

        guard let index = indexOf({ $0.1 == value }) else {
            return nil
        }

        return self[index].0

    }

}
```

Comment: You write that you want to get a value for a given key (which is very common task for dictionaries), but the code sample is trying to do the opposite: find a key for a given value. So what is actually the goal?

Answer (score 0):

This is straight-forward dictionary access; no need to use extensions.

```
var myDictionary = [String:String]()

// At some point strings are put into the dictionary
// e.g. myDictionary["SomeKey"] = "SomeString"
// then you can say

if let someString = myDictionary[key] {
    // You can now do something with someString
}
```

Keys and objects don't have to be strings, of course

I would suggest you read the Swift book from Apple in iBooks and try things out in in a Swift Playground in Xcode.

Comment: well, in my case trouble seems to be that I receive an error for the part someString = myDictionary[key]  - it tells me that the value of optional type String is not unwrapped and encourages me to add an '!', which causes Xcode to stop objecting but the code doesn't work for some reason. The key part is actually a variable whose identity I don't know in advance. Is it even possible to pass in a variable, which is the unknown key whose value I wish to save?

Comment: This is because there may not be an element for that key in the dictionary, so the dictionary access returns an *optional* - this is explained in the Swift Book and here- http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/247/optionals#t=201610262214145417184 Optionals are a very important concept in Swift.  See how my code says `if let ....` this is unwrapping the optional.  The code inside the if only executes if the value of `myDictionary[key]` wasn't nil.  In my example `key` would be a string variable, the value of which is the key you want from the dictionary